# Programar botón de retroceso con mensaje de confirmación android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Quiero implementar un mensaje de confirmación al momento de salir, actualmente utilizo el onSupportNavigateUp() pero no me cierra el activity hasta darlo por segunda vez.

este es el método.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {

        if(OpenDialog() == false){
            onBackPressed();
            mChart.setProgress(0, false); //metodo de notificacion
            return false;

        }
        this.finish();
        return true;
    }
```

Este es el botón

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola amigo, has utilizado el método ´onOptionsItemSelected´ en tu clase?

Comment: No, para que sirve ese?